# empty then repopulate entity collection in EF 5 throws sql exception

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am emptying a collection of entities by removing all the entities it contains and deleting each from the context and then i am repopulating with what could be entities having same primary keys as the ones that have been just removed.

```
protected void RemoveAllElements<T>(System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<T> col, Func<T, bool> deleteIfTrue) where T : System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject
        {

            if (col != null && col.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = col.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    var elt = col.ElementAt(i);
                    if (deleteIfTrue(elt))
                    {
                        col.Remove(elt);
                        DBContextManager.CurrentContext.DeleteObject(elt);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

then i repopulate the collection by adding new entities but when i save i get a constraint violation because entities were not deleted before new ones were inserted.
do i need to save the changes to the context before i add new entities?

Answer (score 0):

Do I need to save the changes to the context before i add new entities?

the answer is yes! When you save the change you're doing a commit to the database, and just after it your alterations are executed.

Comment: even if i delete the existing entities before adding the new ones? I guess it's not intelligent in that regard. oh well